# change axis crosses in Highchart

Tags: excel, highcharts

I draw a chart with Highcharts like this:

[image]

But I want to be like this:

[image]

In Excel there is an option that I can change the axis crosses but I couldn't find any thing like that in Highcharts. please help me to change base line plot into custom number like 2500 in this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got my question!
I did it by changing the chart type to "columnrange" instead of 'column' and specify the low and high value:

[image]